# Symfony - how to convert json string to entity

Tags: php, json, symfony, deserialization, jmsserializerbundle

I would like to map a json string to my entity Poste.

Here is my json output with var_dump :

```
string(695) "{
              "id":2,
              "user": {
                  "id":1,
                  "username":"tom.smith",
                  "email":"tom.smith@gmail.com"
                  // other properties of User class (FOSUserBundle)
                 },
              "description":"cool",
              "nb_comments":0,"nb_likes":0,
              "date_creation":"2014-04-13T20:07:34-0700", 
              "is_there_fashtag":false,
              "fashtags":[]
            }"
```

I tried to deserialize with jmsserializer :

```
$postes[] = $serializer->deserialize($value, 'Moodress\Bundle\PosteBundle\Entity\Poste', 'json');
```

I have an error :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
     Moodress\Bundle\PosteBundle\Entity\Poste::setUser() must be an instance of
     Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User, array given
```

Why am I not able to deserialize a simple entity poste ?

Thanks

Comment: did you map your entities with the correct expose/type methods from JMS Serializer? http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type

Answer (score 1):

Your `$user` property in `Moodress\Bundle\PosteBundle\Entity\Poste` refers to `Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User`. The `setUser()` accepts only a User object, not an array.

I guess you should first create a `$user` with the 'user' array and then pass it to your poste object. In this situation, it seems hard to do it in another way than the one I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23052704/3524372).

```
$data = json_decode($yourJsonFile, true);

$user = new User();
$user->setId($data['user']['id']);
$user->setUsername($data['user']['username']);
// …

$poste = new Poste();
$poste->setId($data['id']);
$poste->setDescription($data['description']);
// …
$poste->setUser($user);
```