# Deserialize nested JSON into entity using Symfony

Tags: php, json, symfony, json-deserialization

How do I deserialize the `photos` collection in to a `Photo` entity using Symfony?

Here is my json:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "status": 1,
    "title": "sometitle",
    "agency": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "AgencyName",
        ...
        "created_at": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+01:00",
        "updated_at": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+01:00"
    },
    "price": "123123",
    ...
    "created_at": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+01:00",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+01:00",
    "photos": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "path": "img1.jpg",
            "created_at": "2018-04-05T15:29:47+02:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-04-05T15:29:47+02:00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "path": "img2.jpg",
            "created_at": "2018-04-05T15:35:28+02:00",
            "updated_at": "2018-04-05T15:35:28+02:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I specify in the `Photo` entity that it should use the collection as manytoone?

This is not working:

```
\Entity\Photo.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="House", inversedBy="photos")
 */
private $house;

\Entity\House.php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photo", mappedBy="house")
 */
private $photos;
```

When I call it in my view:

```
{% for photo in house.photos %}
    <li>{{ photo.path }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

It is throwing an excepting and is trying to send another GET request toa different route in the API instead of just using the nested collection

Comment: $stuff = json_decode($json, true); // true, to preserve assoc. $stuff['photos'][0]['path'] would be the first photo's path, so you would do something like... for photo in $stuff['photos'] I'm guessing if you json_decoded this. I am not great with Symphony, so I only know what to do with core PHP... Json decode & then access the values you want just like an assoc array :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051554/symfony-deserialize-json-to-an-array-of-entities

Comment: @MathieuDormeval not sure if it is. I want to build a web app that doesnt need to connect to mysql and only uses API requests to manage the data. So i went with DoctrineRestDriver. I might have to change to something else. Can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Symfony Serializer Component: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html

example:

```
$house = $serializer->deserialize($json, House::class, 'json');
```